# Choosing between a funded PhD offer and a possibly funded one

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, funding, university

I have been admitted into two PhD programs at universities A and B. A offered me funding, however B asked me to apply for state funding before discussing internal funding. The deadline to accept the offer from A is early January, and I will not recieve the results of my application for state funding at B until February. I really want to go to B, but I am afraid of rejecting A's offer and not getting state or internal funding at B. What should I do?

I was thinking about:

- Asking A for more time to consider my options before taking a decision.
- Contacting B and explaining that I have a fully-funded offer from A, but however, they are my first choice and I need to know whether they will give me funding if I do not get it from the government before rejecting A's offer. A is really prestigious and well placed in rankings, so I though that bringing them up while contacting B would play in my favor.

Would this be a wise approach to my problem? May this just worsen my situation? I would greatly appreciate any advice or suggestion. I am desperate about what to do, this is a really important dilema that I have never faced before.

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable to ask for more time to decide, though do so quickly as many people (at least in the US and EU) will now be on their Christmas holidays and not back in the office til early January, so many not see your request in time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can try those things.  It is unlikely to make your situation worse.  Only A and B know if they are willing to help you.

Comment: Just Mahe sure you don't mention the names of the schools you're debating between. Must say offer from another school...